# longitudinal dataset with multiple binary dependent variables

Tags: mixed-model, cart

I have a dataset where a test (a continuous variable) is administered every 3 months for 2 years for most of the participants (approx 25% have one or two missing scores). There are further time-invariant variables that also needs to be included in the model. The dependent variable is binary and is measured at 5,7 and 10 years. 
A logistic mixed-effect model would have been applicable had the dependent variable only been measured at one time-point, but the multiple time-points for the dependent variable leaves me wondering how this can be modeled. 
Is there any form of tree model that properly accounts for longitudinal correlated data?

Comment: Are the value 5, 7, and 10 numeric variables or categorical?

Answer (score 0):

Why not build a separate model for each dependent variable using all of the data available before the dependent variable was measured?  It would make sense that the independent variables would have a different impact on the dependent variable at 5, 7 and 10 years out.